# How to get ISO property in Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a camera app developed for Windows Phone 8 and everything works OK, except I cannot get ISO or any other property on PhotoCaptureDevice. Whenever I call 
`object value = photoCaptureDevice.GetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.Iso)` I get null back.
Is any special about querying for `KnownCameraPhotoProperties` properties? I do not have problems setting any property.

Comment: Have you tried that code in different devices, or just one?

Comment: I have tried it only on Nokia Lumia 1020.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation for the ISO property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.knowncameraphotoproperties.iso%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Not all values may be supported by each phone. Use the GetSupportedPropertyRange method to learn more about this property.

So use [that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to learn if the phone supports the ISO property before you try to fetch it.

In your case, though, it seems that your Lumia doesn't support it. The only way you'll know that device's ISO is by checking it out with Nokia, or maybe through its manual. You could hard code the ISO for that device, but I think hard coding values for every device that can't tell you its ISO sensitivity is bordering on bad practice. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is supported and returns the range of 100 - 4000. And I can set this property, I just cannot get its value.

Comment: You know... Since your camera can use a range of different sensitivities, I think you have to set which one you want to use in your app, because **maybe it doesn't have a default value**. So try setting it first and see what happens. BTW, the higher the ISO, the less time it takes to capture a photo, right? So 4000 could get a pretty still of a moving car or insect, as long as the environment is bright enough, right? God dammit I want one of those just for the camera now.